# Why do objects get stuck together in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a 2D scene that consists of 4 sprites, each with a box collider.

[image: Boxes]

I then have a prefab that is simply a sprite of a circle with a 2D circle collider.

Finally I have a script named Atmosphere attached to my main camera that will fill the box with lots of instances of the prefab and give them a velocity in a random direction.

using UnityEngine;

```
public class Atmosphere : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Molecule;
    void Start()
    {
        float x = -4.5f;
        while (x < 4.5f)
        {
            float y = -4.5f;
            while (y < 4.5f)
            {
                var inst = GameObject.Instantiate(Molecule);
                inst.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
                var rb = inst.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                float xForce = Random.value * 2f - 1f;
                float yForce = Random.value * 2f - 1f;
                rb.AddForce(new Vector2(xForce, yForce) * 100f);
                y += 0.5f;
            }
            x += 0.5f;
        }
    }
}
```

For a while the dots bounce around against each other and the edges of the box.

[image: Happy bouncing]

But after a while they eventually get stuck to the edges of the box.

[image: Sticky balls]

Both the box and balls and the box walls have the same physics material

[image: Physics material]

Which has zero friction and a bounciness of 1.

[image: Physics material settings]

Why do they stick to the walls, and how can I stop it from happening?

[Download Unity 3D demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rsQVhX9W6-OHIB0C-zksNMd0a9YS3lWc)

**UPDATE**
If I drop a single molecule into the box with the following script attached it gets stuck to the wall immediately.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class Molecule : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D RigidBody2D;

    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
        RigidBody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        float xForce = Random.value * 2f - 1f;
        float yForce = Random.value * 2f - 1f;
        RigidBody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(-.25f, -0.25f) * 100f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a little `Bounciness` to the walls?

Comment: @Morasiu They both share the same physics material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity3D has a velocity threshold. Objects with a velocity below this threshold won't bounce etc.

The solution is to go to **Edit > Project Settings > Physics 2D** and to set the Velocity Threshold lower.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT - The real solution:**

So I was doing some reading on integration techniques and it hit me: The energy you're losing is quite likely coming from numerical inaccuracies stemming from several approximation techniques compounded.

I'm guessing the continuous collision detection algorithm is mostly to blame, floating-point error accumulation, but probably also from numerical integration techniques.

What you're trying to achieve is elastic collision, which means that it satisfies conservation of energy as well as momentum. The trick is going to be for you to add a script to every object that preserves the energy of the system by adding error-correcting velocity over time. Whether you actually use the energy route or not is up to you, there are a number of ways to track and modify the energy resulting in a change of velocity. Momentum would be the would be the easiest to track in my opinion. What you're trying to achieve is elastic collision, which means that it satisfies conservation
i.e.

1. Make a component that preserves the scalar quantity of kinetic energy or momentum (it'll probably produce the same results)
2. When you initialize all the particles with a velocity, make sure to save the starting momentum in the particle's script. I would save the scalar quantity for simplicity, so just use the length of velocity
3. Every frame, in the update event check the velocity of the rigid body. Find the change in momentum or change in energy and add the -difference and apply it to the object.

I doubt you'll have to work on collision events as well, especially if you use the exact same mass for every object. Here's a link with an example where someone corrected unity's friction-less physics using conservation of energy https://answers.unity.com/questions/168393/frictionless-physics.html

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately none of those helped. I didn't try the circle because I want a square. Do you have any other ideas? This seems like a bug.

Comment: Can you get debug output or a label somewhere on the screen? Try the simulation with exactly 1 particle with a starting velocity, and stream the magnitude of the velocity every frame so we can see if and when the energy loss happens. If the velocity ever dips, we can safely say it’s a bug in the CCD. A thought, if they’re using GJK and EPA algorithm, we know that’s actually an approximation and could be causing it. If it does work, the issue lies with the circles and we can try to go from there (may even be a hack in that you could manually fix the magnitude of velocity)

Comment: I can't preserve energy per molecule because having them move at different speeds is part of the purpose. I'm now able to reproduce with a single molecule, see the updated question.

Comment: I actually updated my answer as well last night, and in terms of energy preservation you should be able to preserve the energy by monitoring kinetic vs potential energy regardless of the starting velocity - see the attached link for an example implementation in a unity script. Since elastic collisions preserve energy, the starting velocity differences should not be a problem. I encourage you to check out some elastic collision example problems for some inspiration as well.

Comment: Additionally you should make sure the physical properties of the wall are similar in terms of friction- some engines use a friction mixing approach to collisions which can affect both objects during a collision

Comment: The problem isn't velocity. It seems the problem is when a rigid body hits another object at a certain velocity. Could you try the updated project file and let me know if you see the same problem?

Comment: Yeah, it’s certainly an interesting issue. I’ll take a look at it later today after class, I’ll get back to you tonight

Comment: Jon, did you manage to have a look at this? Do you think it's a Unity bug?

Answer (score 0):

colliders may be stuck in each other for the reason of low contact offset, go to edit-project settings-physics2d and increase the default contact offset a little bit, 0.12 for example, it was work for me.

cheers